# Invert a Scala Future

Tags: scala, future

Is it possible to 'invert' a Scala Future?

Sometimes the result of a Future being a Success means an error. In that case it would be nice to flip a Future, i.e. call a function that returns a Future, which succeeds with a specified value if the original Future fails and fails with a specified Error in case the original Future succeeds.

```
def flip[T](original: Future[T])(value: => T)(error: Throwable): Future[T] = ???
```

Comment: Could you give an example of when Success means an error?

Comment: What's the use case of this feature?

Comment: lets say I am writing a service that creates something only if it doesn't exist already... if it exists I get an error, if it doesn't - I proceed with a result. (I believe I might have to chain it with another future too)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  def craziness[A](future: Future[A])(default : => A)(error: Throwable)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] = {
    val p = Promise[A]()
    import scala.util.{Success, Failure, Try}
    future.onComplete {
      case _: Success[_] => p.failure(error)
      case _: Failure[_] => p.complete(Try(default))
    }
    p.future
  }
```

Here's a repl session showing it work:

```
scala> val f1 = craziness[String](Future("hello!"))("my crazy default")(new Throwable("boom"))
f1: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@4d154ccd

scala> f1 onComplete { println }
Failure(java.lang.Throwable: boom)

scala> val f2 = craziness[String](Future(throw new Exception("boom!")))("my crazy default")(new Throwable("boom"))
f2: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1890516e

scala> f2 onComplete { println }
Success(my crazy default)
```

EDIT:

for completeness, `def craziness[A](future: Future[A])` should probably be `def craziness[A](future: => Future[A])`

Comment: Unfortunately the solution is flawed. if `default` throws…

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after `recover` and `recoverWith` constructs. Here's a quick REPL session to show its usage.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val failFuture = Future(sys.error("BOOM"))
failFuture: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@6e06451e

scala> val defaultValue = 100
defaultValue: Int = 100

scala> val futureRecoveredWithDefaultFuture = failFuture.recoverWith { case e: RuntimeException => Future.successful(defaultValue) }
futureRecoveredWithDefaultFuture: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@130161f7

scala> val futureRecoveredWithDefaultValue = failFuture.recover { case e: RuntimeException => defaultValue }
futureRecoveredWithDefaultValue: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3b69e7d1
```

Checking if this really works:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala> import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.Await

scala> val res1 = Await.result(futureRecoveredWithDefaultFuture, 1.second)
res1: Int = 100

scala> val res2 = Await.result(futureRecoveredWithDefaultValue, 1.second)
res2: Int = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala 2.12 you'll be able to use [`transform`](https://github.com/viktorklang/blog/blob/master/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-3.md) and [`transformWith`](https://github.com/viktorklang/blog/blob/master/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-4.md) to make this trivial.

But until then this should get you there:

```
implicit class InvertFuture[T](val fut: Future[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def flip(recover: Throwable => T)(fail: T => Throwable)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[T] =
        fut.recover({ case t => recover(t) }).map(t => throw fail(t))
}

// And usage:

scala> Future(1).flip(_ => 2)(_ => throw new IllegalStateException("ohnoes!")) onComplete println
Failure(java.lang.IllegalStateException: ohnoes!)
```